# Android application doesn't work properly launched on phone

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

A really weird thing started to happen and I can't find the answer. I am using real device, not emulator, to run my app and it was running just fine until now... The thing is if i am opening the app **through android studio** and it launches on my phone, it works fine. But if i close and open it again **through the phone** a moment after, it doesn't work properly (firebase doesn't work properly actually)...

And it all started after i submitted my app to the internal testing on google play console. At first, Debug version worked fine, but version from google play testing didn't. For some reason now, neither one works, only launched from android studio on my pc. There are 3 SHA1 certificates in firebase: debug and two other taken from google play.

(App is published for a while now, i just submitted new version to the internal testing. **Older versions works fine** both from google play and installed from .apk, b**ut new ones i made today doesn't** for some reason.)

And I really have no idea where I should start to look for a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved the issue, it had nothing to do with firebase. The thing is, i used statement `if(intent.extras == null)` and that code works *only in debug* and running it *only for the first time* for some reason, even though i am not adding any extras, so it must be some adjustments by the android studio itself, that's why statement wasn't executed and since i had stuff with firebase only in there, i assummed that was it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check having separate `google-services.json` for `debug` and `release`?

Comment: No, I have only one file in the main directory. What should be the difference inside between release and debug? Or they should be the same, just different paths?